# Alternatives to passing an object over and over again

Tags: c++, interface, singleton, dependencies

There are a couple of classes which are meant to be derived by other classes pretty often. They are user input receivers, like a key down receiver, a key release receiver, mouse move receiver and so on. Classes that inherit from those are for example the hotkey-action, which inherits from key down receiver and key release receiver, or a camera-rotator, which inherits from mouse move receiver. The input a user does will be forwarded by another class to the corresponding receivers, thus any input receiver, e.g. the camera-rotator, needs to register itself in that forwarding class. The class that forwards the inputs is always the same, there are never two.

When users of my class create a new input receiver, a class that inherits from e.g. the mouse move receiver, the mouse move receiver needs to know the forwarding class in order to register itself for receiving mouse inputs. So the code of the mouse move receiver constructor looks like this:

```
mouseMoveReceiverIF(inputforwarder* ifo)
{
    ifo.registerInputReceiver(this);
}
```

Since it's clear that there is only one inputforwarder, it's not only less intuitive if the user has to pass it, but also it's additional typing for each input-receiver created.

But if i'd make the inputforwarder a singleton or a global variable, so that the input receivers can access it without the need for the user to pass it in the constructor, i'd have other problems: Then the user needed to know that the inputforwarder has to exist before any inputforwarder is created. Nothing would warn him, nothing would force him to create the inputforwarder first. The program would simply crash, because the input receiver would try to register with an inexistant input forwarder. And that would be even worse.

How does an effective and proper way look like? What are alternatives to the above mentioned examples?

Thanks!

Comment: Your design is overly complicated (and I mean *really* overly complicated (yes, it's FUBAR and you have to start over (yes, really))). Reduce inheritance, preferably to zero, and take a look at polymorphic functions (`std::function` from `<functional>` helps here).

Comment: @Zoidberg: Thanks for your hint. I'm an unexperienced programmer, and the design that looks terrible to you, looks good to me - i don't know when and why it would make troubles and the way it is now, it is easy to use: The user creates an input receiver that inherits from the desired base input receiver (e.g. keydown receiver) and just needs to implement the onKeyDown method. I'm not sure about what you mean with using polymorphic functions. Something like a functor template? And using it to register any classe's method (or any other function) with the input forwarder? (If so, why that way?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I would question whether you should hide the instance of InputForwarder from the user. The user code that calls these constructors is configuring the system and setting up dependencies -- quite possibly the code *should* state those dependencies explicitly, even though that means typing an extra constructor parameter.

Assuming you are going to hide it, it depends how the input forwarder is created:

- if it can be created without parameters, make it like a self-starting service. That is, you have a function that returns "the" instance, and if that doesn't exist when the function is called then the function creates it.
- if it takes parameters supplied by the user, then it can't be a self-starting service. You could provide a global "default input forwarder instance" that is set by the user, then in the constructor check for the existence of this instance -- if it's there register with it or otherwise raise an exception.

In case you're concerned, testability is probably a non-issue here. Even if you have a global "default" instance to hide the dependency from normal users, you can still have the constructor like this:

```
mouseMoveReceiverIF(inputforwarder* ifo = 0)
{
    if (!ifo) {
        ifo = getDefaultIfo();
        // check for null again if necessary
    }
    ifo.registerInputReceiver(this);
}
```

So you can inject whatever inputforwarder is appropriate for testing.

Comment: Thanks! The forwarder is created without parameters. Your proposal does the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a singleton of inputforwarder,
and make sure to initialize it on program start.
So that now it will not be possible for any client to access it before it was created.

One more thing about your design:
you might want to consider using the Decorator pattern for specialization of recivers.

**Edit:**
And if you don't want a singleton pattern (because of unit testing etc...)
than a factory method will do the trick,
something like : InputReceiverFactory.GetInputReceiver()

Comment: With the singleton the user would still have to know or not to forget to initialize it on program start to prevent the crash, as there still would be no warning if he wouldn't. The factory however sounds like a good alternative, thanks!

Comment: Singleton can initialize itself of first call to its Instance Method, i.e lazy initialization. this can be done in the naive way or to support cross-thread calls with safety.it can also init itself when it is loaded into memory i.e eager initalization. it is usually of no concermn of the client to init the singleton anyway. the factory is only better for unit tests and to support loose coupling, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

2 suggestions:

1) Make an Init function/static class member that creates the input forwarder for you. This is a nice form of encapsulation.

2) Make the inputforwarder class a static class with all static members and a private constructor. If anything needs to be initialized, you would do that with an init class method.

Hope this helps. I hear that static classes are a bad practice sometimes, but if you don't want to revert to functions, namespaces would be the only other solution. (that I know of)

Comment: "Make the inputforwarder class a static class with all static members and a private constructor. If anything needs to be initialized, you would do that with an init class method." y u no namespace.

Comment: Thanks. I think that will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your design could you make the `inputforwarder` part of the class via templating?  Then you could automatically have it call the correct forwarder.

Personally I would keep away from singletons - they tend to make unit testing difficult.

Comment: I don't understand your proposal. The inputforwarder part of which class via templating? Mind to post a small example?